# Inbound E-Mail has problems with utf-8?

Tags: apex, email

I have a problem with an inbound E-Mail. In my Apex code I just use the following:

```
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String myMailContent = email.plainTextBody;
    String someLine = myMailContent.split('\n', 0)[4];
    .....
}
```

Now the problem is, that in my E-Mail program the E-Mail displays special chars, but when I use `someLine` and assign it to lets say `Lead.OtherStreet`, it doesn't display special chars like "ö, ü, ä, ß".

I have heard that Apex automatically uses utf-8 for inbound e-mails, so I really don't get, what could be the problem here?

Does anyone have a clue, why that happens?

Comment: inbound emails from your email client might not be encoding the body as UTF-8

Comment: Hey, see my edit. The mails are perfectly fine

Comment: Frederick, to get better assistance from the community, you'll need to expose more of the chain of transformations that is occurring and where it goes wrong. If system.debug in the apex inboundemailHandler shows the characters correctly, then they are coming in as UTF-8.  So, we need to see more of each step along the way and what you observe using system.debug and screen shots